# install clickonce application on the same machine, under different logins

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, clickonce

I know it's not possible to isntall a clickonce application for all users, due to a limitation with the technology and what it's purpose is. My problem is this...I have a Windows Forms application I've build, and deployed using ClickOnce. It uses user settings, 2 to be exact to store some information that the application needs.

Now I can install the application fine and it works...But if I login as another user, it looses it's settings. Is there a way to have the settings global to the application, so that if I install it for a second, or third user, it doesn't remove settings in place, when it was installed for the first user?

Not sure if changing my settings from User to Application, would fix this or not. Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing to `app.exe.config` is the correct way to do it.  It works nicely even across version upgrades.

Comment: But application settings are read only and I need to be able to write to the settings....This is why I used user settings in Visual Studio and not application settings. How can I still achieve this with application settings?

Comment: After looking into it more, you are correct. I will give that a go and see what happens...Thanks :)